# Live click event reporting different source in Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: jquery, event-handling, cross-browser, jquery-events

With this HTML

```
<div>
  <button>
    <img src="https://img.skitch.com/20110912-1m2qj31m7sxmh46uheef63gutu.gif">
  </button>
</div>
```

and this jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("body").live("click", function(event) {
    $("body").append(event.target.tagName);            
  });
});
```

**Why is the event target node in Chrome the image and in Firefox it's the button?**

jsfiddle test -> http://jsfiddle.net/MikeGrace/YC5A7/

Comment: Weird. Seems like IE/FF don't want disabled buttons from inner content. While Chrome does it the logical way :(

Comment: @Mike Grace: It's the `BUTTON` for me in Chrome. _Edit:_ The image was not loaded for me, but I see what you mean.

Comment: that's interesting: if you click almost in the border it says 'button' in chrome :?

Comment: Oh noes! you're using live. That makes jQuery developers sad :( try delegate(). http://paulirish.com/2010/on-jquery-live/

Comment: It's button in IE9 also. And check it out if you move the positioning a little. http://jsfiddle.net/gmaZG/

Comment: @OscarGodson As of jQuery 1.7, both `.live` and `.delegate` are converted into `.on` methods internally. However, it's still true that you're better off assigning `.on` to the closest DOM container (`.delegate` style) instead of the entire document (`.live` style) whenever possible.

Comment: @Blazemonger yep. That was posted back in September. LONG LIVE on()!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't limited to images, of course -- I tweaked your code at http://jsfiddle.net/YC5A7/13/ and got the same result with an ordinary hyperlink.

According to the jQuery docs, [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) "can be the element that registered for the event or a descendant of it." So your results are consistent with the intended purpose of that method.

However, [event.currentTarget](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) has the desired result in all browsers: http://jsfiddle.net/YC5A7/16/